# How to store data in Keithley2400 buffer during measurements and retrieve through rs232?

Tags: python, serial-port, instruments, visa, pyvisa

I am trying to do an IV measurement (source current, sense voltage) store into the Keithley2400 buffer and retrieve the measured data (voltage and current) into my python program variable 'data'.

```
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
connected_list=rm.list_resources()
print(connected_list) # list[0] is RS-232 reference
Ki2400 = rm.open_resource(connected_list[0])
Ki2400.read_termination = '\r'
Ki2400.timeout=5000
print(Ki2400.query('*IDN?'))

Ki2400.write('*RST')
Ki2400.write(':sens:func:conc off')
Ki2400.write(':sour:func current')
Ki2400.write(":sens:func 'volt:dc'")
Ki2400.write(':SENS:VOLT:NPLC 0.01')
Ki2400.write(':sens:volt:prot 30')
Ki2400.write(':source:current:start 1e-12')
Ki2400.write(':source:current:stop 100e-3')
#Ki2400.write(':source:current:step 4e-4')
Ki2400.write(':source:sweep:points 500')
Ki2400.write(':source:current:mode sweep')
Ki2400.write(':sour:swe:rang auto')
Ki2400.write(':sour:swe:spac log')
Ki2400.write(':trig:coun 500')
Ki2400.write(':sour:del 0.1')
Ki2400.write('output on')
Ki2400.write('read?')
data=Ki2400.read()
Ki2400.write(':outp off')
```

However this produces the following error:

```
VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_ASRL_OVERRUN (-1073807252): An overrun error occurred during transfer. A character was not read from the hardware before the next character arrived.
```

I am not sure if I am coding the storing in buffer and reading it correctly. Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I tried looking up the error, and was able to find some threads on [National Instruments' website](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/Visa-Read-Error-1073807252/td-p/2240616?profile.language=en) and it seems that your buffer might be too small or that you're not reading fast enough. [This thread from GitHub](https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa/issues/174) details some ways that you might be able to use to increase buffer size, so you'd want something like:

```
from visa import constants
rm.visalib.set_buffer(Ki2400.session, constants.VI_IO_IN_BUF, 20)
rm.visalib.set_buffer(Ki2400.session, constants.VI_IO_OUT_BUF, 20)
```

At the top of your code. Alternatively maybe you can change

```
Ki2400.write('read?')
data=Ki2400.read()
```

Into

```
data = Ki2400.query('read?')
```

because this might read slightly faster.